# SFDX CLI fails to connect to orgs with JSON error

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-falcon

I am using the latest CLI version `6.35.1-8b7320f7c2` and when I do

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -a DevHub -d
```

> ERROR:  Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 88.

Calling

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

renders a Syntax error in the CONNECTION STATUS

```
=== Orgs
     ALIAS   USERN             ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ──────  ────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
(D)  DevHub  robert@email.com  00D50000000IOZFEA4  SyntaxError
```

[image]

Comment: Experienced this same error working on a Trailhead module and found that I needed to replace my entire sfdx-project.json file with new content to make it work. Not sure if there was a bad character in the original or what.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For reasons best known to itself, DX tries to parse your `sfdx-project.json` file even when your operation isn't related to any particular project e.g. when you run

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

So, check the `sfdx-project.json` in your current directory for errors, or change directory to a known-good project.